# How to append strings to other strings in a data set?

Tags: string, powershell, append

I want to append several strings in a data set with custom strings.

**Example**

Content of Dataset:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

Result after appending:

```
Test1.com
Test2.com
Test3.com
```

Would I have to use regex to parse to the end of each Test[n] to be able to append it with a custom string (`.com`)? Has anyone got an example that describes exactly how to do it?

I am reading from a SQL-Table and writing values into a DataSet which is exported to CSV the following way:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTO-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NotypeInformation |`% { $_ -replace '"','' } |  out-file  $outfile -Encoding "unicode"
```

The DataSet contains of Strings such as:

```
Banana01
Banana02
Apple01
Cherry01
Cherry02
Cherry03
```

The thing I want to do is append `.com` to only `Cherry01`, `Cherry02`, and `Cherry03`, and after appending `.com`, export it as a CSV file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many ways. Here are a few:

```
# Using string concatenation
'Test1','Test2','Test3' | Foreach-Object{ $_ + '.com' }

# Using string expansion
'Test1','Test2','Test3' | Foreach-Object{ "$_.com" }

# Using string format
'Test1','Test2','Test3' | Foreach-Object{ "{0}{1}" -f $_,'.com' }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me an example related to the code that I have posted?

Comment: What are the column headers for each value you want to append to?

Comment: All the strings I want to append got the header "vmname"

Comment: Try something like: ... | Foreach-Object{ $_.vmname + '.com' }

Comment: $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTO-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NotypeInformation |`% { $_ -replace '"','' }| Foreach-Object {$T=$_.vmname
if($T -match "ESX\d\d" -or $T -match "ESX\d\d\d") {$T + '.com'} Else{$T} } | out-file  $outfile -Encoding "unicode"

is giving me an empty result.

Comment: If vmname is a column defined in the table[0] :$DataSet.Tables[0] | Foreach-Object{ $_.vmname + '.com' }

Comment: If I am doing it like this, I am receiving a CSV file with strange content like this: #TYPE System.string "Length" "18" "18 "18" "9" "9" and so on

Comment: But, do you get the correct values before you pipe to the csv file? If so, try this: $DataSet.Tables[0] | Foreach-Object{ $_.vmname=$_.vmname + '.com'; $_ }

Comment: yes, I was getting correct results before piping the CSV. It's working the way you wrote it, but now every element in the vmname colum is being appended with .com. How do I integrate this into an IF query, so that only name starting with "Cherry" are getting appended with.com?

Comment: $DataSet.Tables[0] | Where-Object{ $_.vmname -eq 'Cherry'} | Foreach-Object {$_.vmname = $_.vmname + '.com'; $_ }

Comment: On a second thought, the previous example will pass on just objects who's vmname equals cherry. Use this instead:

$DataSet.Tables[0] | foreach { if($_.vmname -eq 'Cherry'){$_.vmname = $_.vmname + '.com'; $_ } else {$_} }

Comment: excellent! Instead of "-eq" I was using "-match" since I used regular expressions.. This line is what I am using now: $DataSet.Tables[0] | foreach { if($_.vmname -match '^Cherry\d\d'){$_.vmname = $_.vmname + '.com'; $_ } else {$_} } | ConvertTO-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NotypeInformation |`% { $_ -replace '"','' }|  out-file  $outfile -Encoding "unicode"

Answer (score 9):

You could use something like this:

Example 1

```
$t = "test"
$t = $t + ".com"
```

Example 2

```
$test = @("test1","test2")

$test | ForEach-Object {
$t = $_ + ".com"
Write-Host $t}
```

With your added code I did this. I don't have a database to test it on, so I made the data set manually, so you might just have to change the **$DataSet[0]** in my code to **$DataSet.Tables[0]**.

```
$DataSet[0] | ConvertTO-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NotypeInformation  | Foreach-Object{$T=$_
IF($T -match "(Cherry\d\d)"){$T = $T -replace "(Cherry\d\d)(.+)",'$1.com$2'};$T } |  out-file  $outfile -Encoding "unicode"
```

Comment: Thank you. I have posted some code in my post, would be cool if u could have a look at it.

Comment: Its hard to test cause i dont have access to sql , so just check it out and if its not correct i can try sort it out for you.

Comment: Thanks. But I think this way each string will be appended, no matter what it is starting with.. But I only want to append those with .com which start with "Cherry#", as I posted in the edit in my initial post.

Comment: Ok sorry did not see that part try the code now after i edited it,the edited code check if any thing is called cherry + two digits e.g cherry00,cherry01,cherry99

Comment: Thank you. I have tested it and it seems to work but what if I am having something like this in the DataSet: Cherry01,fruit,yummy then .com will be attached to yummy what makes it Cherry01,fruit,yummy.com. What if I want to insert it only after the name Cherry01 so it looks like: Cherry01.com,fruit,yummy

Comment: It looks for any thing that is **cherry** + 2 digits. It would not do any thing to **yummy** .But if you only ever want to change Cherry01 then just change this "(Cherry\d\d)" to be "(Cherry01)"

Comment: yes, but if it is a row like this: Cherry01,fruit,yummy the .com is attached to the end of the line.. in this case it's Cherry01,fruit,yummy.com. Sorry for being so special about it, but I really want to learn it :)

Comment: I am not sure could you post all the code and an example of the table in sql so i could try it because in my example $DataSet="Cherry01,fruit,yummy" and the code would check each one

Answer (score 0):

`$array | %{if($_ -match "^Cherry\d\d"){$_ += ".com"};$_}`